# capture http status code using apollo in angular

Tags: angular, angular7, apollo, apollo-client

am new to angular. I am using Apollo client to execute graphql queries. I need to check the status code which I get and return the message. please help me to do the same.
 this is the code I used.how to capture the status code which I get .the attachment will show how I get the status code.[image]

```
let res = this.apollo.use('dataManipulation').query({
      query: myquery,
      fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
      variables:{
        userId: this.userId
      }      
    });
     res.subscribe(listData => {
      this.studyData=[];
      this.resourceData=listData.data['StudyList'];
      this.resourceData.entry.forEach(data =>{

        const customFormat= {
          id:data.resource.id,
          title:data.resource.title,

        }

        this.studyData.push(customFormat);
        console.log("studyData",this.studyData)
      });    
    },
      err => {
        console.log("----------",err);
      }
    );
```

Answer (score 3):

If it's for each message, I suggest you to use the [HTTP Interceptor](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor).

```
@Injectable()
export class YouInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor() { }

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(request).pipe(
      catchError(error => this.handleError(error))
    );
  }

  private handleError(error: HttpErrorResponse): Observable<any> {
    if (error.status === 404) {
      // Do your thing here       }
    return EMPTY;
  }
}
```

and import it:

```
@NgModule({
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  imports: [...],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: YouInterceptor,
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: can you please explain me..here i get the response code 401 and the message is unauthorized. so how will i code for it

Comment: If you want to handle, the error 401, then replace in the code 503 by 401 and do your strategy inside the `if`.

You can see an example [here](https://medium.com/@ryanchenkie_40935/angular-authentication-using-the-http-client-and-http-interceptors-2f9d1540eb8) of HttpInterceptor

Answer (score 0):

Apollo provides a comprehensive way of handling errors through Links, specifically [apollo-error-link](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-link/tree/master/packages/apollo-link-error). Unlike using an HttpInterceptor, this allows you to specify logic for both network errors as well as errors included inside of the response as part of the `errors` array:

```
import { onError } from 'apollo-link-error';

const link = onError(({ graphQLErrors, networkError }) => {
  if (graphQLErrors)
    graphQLErrors.map(({ message, locations, path }) =>
      console.log(
        `[GraphQL error]: Message: ${message}, Location: ${locations}, Path: ${path}`,
      ),
    );

  if (networkError){
    console.log(`[Network error]: Status: ${networkError.statusCode}`);
  }
});
```

This link can also be combined with [apollo-link-retry](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-link/tree/master/packages/apollo-link-retry) for even smoother error handling. Links are composed and then passed to your client's constructor, for example:

```
const errorLink = onError(...);
const httpLink = new HttpLink(...);
const link = ApolloLink.from([
  errorLink,
  httpLink,
]);

const client = new ApolloClient({
  link,
  ...
})
```